# JavaScript output returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements, undefined

I recently started JavaScript and been working on a simple calculator for taxes, only problem that I have is that the output returns `undefined` instead of the expected value. For example, when I input 320000, the income tax should be 14000, but it returns undefined. I tried setting `calculation` to `0` but it didn't fix the problem. What makes my function not return the expected value? I looked at example programs given by my college that use variables within conditionals and they work fine, but mine isn't.

```js
function calculateTax()
{
    var taxableIncome, calculation;
    taxableIncome = document.getElementById("t").value * 1;

    if (taxableIncome > 250000) {
        calculation = 0;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 250000 && taxableIncome < 40000) {
        calculation = (taxableIncome - 250000) * 0.20; 
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 400000 && taxableIncome < 800000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 400000) * 0.25) + 30000;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 800000 && taxableIncome < 2000000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 800000) * 0.30) + 130000;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 2000000 && taxableIncome < 8000000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 2000000) * 0.32);
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 8000000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 8000000) * 0.35) + 2410000;
    }

    document.getElementById("inputTax").innerHTML = "The taxable income is:" +taxableIncome;
    document.getElementById("incomeTax").innerHTML = "The income tax is:" +calculation;
}
```

```html
<h1>Income Tax Calculator</h1>

<p>
<label for = "t">Taxable Income</label> 
<input type = "number" id="t" name="t">
<button onclick = "calculateTax()"> Calculate Tax </button>
</p>

<h2 id="inputTax"></h2>
<h2 id="incomeTax"></h2>
```

Comment: It will work when you input an amount > 250000, but you didn't cover the case in your `if...else` for when it is less than that. So it is normal you get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the value `320000`, the condition is always *true* for `taxableIncome > 250000` and returns `0`. Also, there is mismatch between the value `40000` (used in the second condition) and `400000` (used in the third condition).

You should change the following first two condition as:

`if (taxableIncome < 250000) {`

`else if (taxableIncome > 250000 && taxableIncome < 400000) {`

**Please Note:** You do not need to check the final condition (`taxableIncome > 8000000`), only `else` will do.

**Demo:**

```js
function calculateTax()
{
    var taxableIncome, calculation;
    taxableIncome = document.getElementById("t").value * 1;

    if (taxableIncome < 250000) {
        calculation = 0;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 250000 && taxableIncome < 400000) {
        calculation = (taxableIncome - 250000) * 0.20; 
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 400000 && taxableIncome < 800000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 400000) * 0.25) + 30000;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 800000 && taxableIncome < 2000000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 800000) * 0.30) + 130000;
    }
    else if (taxableIncome > 2000000 && taxableIncome < 8000000) {
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 2000000) * 0.32);
    }
    else{
        calculation = ((taxableIncome - 8000000) * 0.35) + 2410000;
    }

    document.getElementById("inputTax").innerHTML = "The taxable income is:" +taxableIncome;
    document.getElementById("incomeTax").innerHTML = "The income tax is:" +calculation;
}
```

```html
<h1>Income Tax Calculator</h1>

<p>
<label for = "t">Taxable Income</label> 
<input type = "number" id="t" name="t">
<button onclick = "calculateTax()"> Calculate Tax </button>
</p>

<h2 id="inputTax"></h2>
<h2 id="incomeTax"></h2>
```

Comment: You only need to check whether the if statement is less than something, because there are part of an "if else" statement. The last `else if taxableIncome` can be just an else statement.

Comment: It works fine, now. Thanks! I didn't notice the missed 0 for 400000.